# SQL identifier substitution - Using a list of column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, psycopg2

I am trying to run a query of the form:

`SELECT {} from TABLE where foo = VALUE`

But I want to be able to provide a list to replace the {}

According to the psycopg docs, in order to do this safely, you need to use the `sql.Identifier` function, in order to properly escape the parameter, and then do something like this:

```
SQL = sql.SQL(
    "SELECT {} FROM foo WHERE bar = %s"
).format(identifier)

cursor.execute(SQL, [VALUE])
```

This works, when `identifier` is a single element, but I need it to be an arbitrary number. For example if:

`identifier = ["abc", "def"]`

and

`VALUE = 4`

`SQL = SELECT abc def FROM foo WHERE bar = 4`

I've tried running `sql.Identifier(x)` for every member of `identifier`, but that gave `"abc""def"`, which is clearly not correct.

Comment: Any reason why this is tagged Django? Can't you do this with the Django-ORM?

Comment: @Saturnix Because it's django's cursor object, but it's not a big deal. I can't use the ORM here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [sql.join()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL.join), to make it work like a list comprehension:

```
from psycopg2 import sql

cols = ["abc", "def"]
query = sql.SQL(
    "select {0} from {1} where abc = %s").format(
        sql.SQL(', ').join([sql.Identifier(c) for c in cols]),
        sql.Identifier('foo')
)
cur = conn.cursor()
print(query)
print(cur.mogrify(query, ('1', )))
cur.execute(query, ('1', ))
print (cur.rowcount, cur.fetchall())
```

Output:

```
Composed([SQL('select '), Composed([Identifier('abc'), SQL(', '), Identifier('def')]), SQL(' from '), Identifier('foo'), SQL(' where abc = %s')])
select "abc", "def" from "foo" where abc = '1'
(1, [('1', '2')])
```

Comment: This escapes the column names like so: `"foo"`, instead of `foo`, which postgres doesn't seem to like...

Comment: This works, just edited the answer. Do you receive any errors ?

Comment: The error is that the column doesn't exist. The query works without quotes around the column names.

Answer (score 0):

In case the accepted answer isn't working for someone, which it should, try these two things:

1 - Make sure there's no **typo** in the column name, and that it **exists in the `{0}` table**. Any of these failing  would print the same error message, but the problem wouldn't be from the double quotes!

2 - This is a work around which will probably tell you the issue was in fact **"1-"**. psycopg2 is expecting double-quoted identifiers so Maurice's answer should work. However, if you really need to remove them for some reason you can do:

```
query = query.as_string(cur).replace("\"",r"")
```

and execute that.