# Passing table name and list of values as argument to psycopg2 query

Tags: sql, python-3.x, psycopg2

#### Context

I would like to pass a table name along with query parameters in a [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) query in a [`python3`](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/) function.

If I understand correctly, I should not format the query string using python [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) method prior to the execution of the query, but let [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) do that.

#### Issue

I can't succeed passing both the table name and the parameters as argument to my query string.

#### Code sample

Here is a code sample:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
connection_string = "host={} port={} dbname={} user={} password={}".format(*PARAMS.values())

conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
curs = conn.cursor()

table = 'my_customers'
cities = ["Paris", "London", "Madrid"]
data = (table, tuple(customers))

query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE city = ANY (%s);")

curs.execute(query, data)
rows = cursLocal.fetchall()
```

#### Error(s)

But I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I also tried to replace the `data` definition by:

```
data = (sql.Identifier(table), tuple(object_types))
```

But then this error pops:

```
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Identifier'
```

If I put `ANY {}` instead of `ANY (%s)` in the query string, in both previous cases this error shows:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: ...* FROM {} WHERE c...
                  ^
```

Initially, I didn't used the [`sql`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) module and I was trying to pass the `data` as the second argument to the curs.[`execute()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) method, but then the table name was single quoted in the command, which caused troubles. So I gave the [`sql`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) module a try, hopping it's not a deprecated habit.
If possible, I would like to keep the curly braces `{}` for parameters substitution instead of `%s`, except if it's a bad idea.

#### Environment

Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit `5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)

```
psycopg2.__version__    
'2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'
```

Comment: The name of the table cannot be a parameter. You must insert it into the query text literally (substitute the placeholder with the variable value) or use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Akina I think your comment could be an answer

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong If I could add some code, I could write an answer. But I don't understand anything about Python... Add it if you can - I don't mind.

Comment: Is there some reasons for not passing a table name as part of a query string? A simple string construction would make it, even if it's less 'safe'. I need to pass N different tables as parameters of my function, so, I don't really want to duplicate N-time my function for that.

Comment: You could use `psycopg2.sql` to generate the query, you might want to have a look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172051/sql-identifier-substitution-using-a-list-of-column-names/58173079#58173079

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```py
table = 'my_customers'
cities = ["Paris", "London", "Madrid"]

query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE city = ANY (%s)").format(sql.Identifier(table))

curs.execute(query, (cities,))
rows = cursLocal.fetchall()
```